# find if there are any null row in left join linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

Table 1 is as follows:

```
|ID  | StartDate   | FoodID  |
|----|-------------|---------|
|5   | 21 May 2021 |F1       |
|6   | 27 Sep 2021 |F2       |
```

Table 2 is as follows:

```
|ID2 |  ID |       Date   |  Value |
|----|-----|--------------|--------|
|1   |  5  |  21 May 2021 |  10    |
|2   |  5  |  24 May 2021 |  20    |
|3   |  5  |  25 May 2021 |  30    |
|4   |  5  |  26 May 2021 |  40    |
|5   |  5  |  Till Today  |  50    |
|6   |  6  |  27 Sep 2021 |  60    |
|7   |  6  |  Till Today  |  70    |
```

Query should return true if there is no missing row in table 2 else false. Please help in defining requiredQuery. 22 and 23 May are weekend days so can be skipped.

```
from t1 in table1
join t2 in table2 on t1.ID equals t2.ID into temp
from leftjoinvar in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
group new {t1, t2} by new {t1.FoodID} into g
select new myVM {
    theFoodName = g.Key.FoodID,
    isRowMissingForTheFoodName = requiredQuery
}

<ol>
    @foreach (var data in Model)
    {
        <li>@data.theFoodName -- @data.isRowMissingForTheFoodName</li>
    }
</ol>
```

For the above example, result needed

1. F1 -- true
2. F2 -- true

Comment: Could you please show us your code?

Comment: @Marco i think i will need to use left join so I have come up with just -- from t1 in table1 join t2 in table2 on t1.ID equals t2.ID into temp from leftjoinvar in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()

Comment: Please add it to your question using the edit button and the elaborate why it is not working and what your end result would look like.

Comment: @Marco I have updated question with code. Please check. Also I have no direction for requiredQuery. Its the main logic needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code below could help you. If you uncomment lines in generic list `t2` it will return `true` otherwise it will return `false`. The code joins two tables and selects the count of `null` valued lines in `table2`. You can refer also to this ([Left Join in Linq With Examples](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/left-outer-join-in-linq/)) blog post.

```
    class Table1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    class Table2
    {
        public int Id2 { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void LeftJoinTest()
    {
        List<Table1> t1 = new List<Table1> {
            new Table1{ Id = 5 },
            new Table1{ Id = 6 },
        };

        List<Table2> t2 = new List<Table2> {
            new Table2{ Id2 = 1, Id = 5 },
            new Table2{ Id2 = 2, Id = 5 },
            new Table2{ Id2 = 3, Id = 5 },
            new Table2{ Id2 = 4, Id = 5 },
            new Table2{ Id2 = 5, Id = 5 },
            //new Table2{ Id2 = 6, Id = 6 },
            //new Table2{ Id2 = 7, Id = 6 },
        };

        var result = t1
            .GroupJoin(t2, id => id.Id, id2 => id2.Id, (id, id2) => new { id.Id, id2 })
            .SelectMany(x => x.id2.DefaultIfEmpty(), (id1, id2) => new { id1, id2 })
            .Count(x => x.id2 == null) == 0;
    }
```

Comment: I have updated my question with some code. Could you please have a look? Meanwhile, I am going through your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I worked in the direction of what @Alisettar Huseynli suggested. First, I counted what estimated number of entries should be there in the table. Then I counted the entries actually present in the table. If Actual entries are less than estimated entries then return false. I have a bigger query and this question is only a part hence not adding the code.